# Adding an extra row for each subject ID and maintaining the values in the other columns

Tags: r

I want to add an extra row for each subject ID in the data frame (below). This row should have `TIME=0` and `DV=0`. Other values in the other columns should stay the same. The data frame looks like the following:

```
ID  TIME  DV  DOSE pH
1    1    5    50  4.6 
1    5    10   50  4.6
2    1    6    100 6.0
2    7    10   100 6.0
```

After adding the extra row, it should look like this:

```
ID  TIME  DV  DOSE pH
1    0    0    50  4.6
1    1    5    50  4.6 
1    5    10   50  4.6
2    0    0    100 6.0
2    1    6    100 6.0
2    7    10   100 6.0
```

How could I achieve this in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
#dummy data
df <- read.table(text="ID  TIME  DV  DOSE pH
1    1    5    50  4.6 
1    5    10   50  4.6
2    1    6    100 6.0
2    7    10   100 6.0",header=TRUE)

#data with zeros
df1 <- df
df1[,c(2,3)] <- 0
df1 <- unique(df1)

#rowbind and sort
res <- rbind(df,df1)
res <- res[order(res$ID,res$TIME),]
res
#    ID TIME DV DOSE  pH
# 11  1    0  0   50 4.6
# 1   1    1  5   50 4.6
# 2   1    5 10   50 4.6
# 31  2    0  0  100 6.0
# 3   2    1  6  100 6.0
# 4   2    7 10  100 6.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Smart way of doing it :)

Comment: Happy it worked, but depending on size of the data, `data.table` option might perform better. Also, with `data.table` option you would avoid intermediate variables: `df1` and `res`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another possible `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[c(1L, seq_len(.N))], ID][, 
            indx := seq_len(.N), ID][indx == 1L, 2:3 := 0][]
#    ID TIME DV DOSE  pH indx
# 1:  1    0  0   50 4.6    1
# 2:  1    1  5   50 4.6    2
# 3:  1    5 10   50 4.6    3
# 4:  2    0  0  100 6.0    1
# 5:  2    1  6  100 6.0    2
# 6:  2    7 10  100 6.0    3
```

Comment: How about `dt[, rbind(list(0,0,DOSE[1L], pH[1L]), .SD), by=ID]`?

Comment: Hmm, yes it seems a similar solution to @zx8754 though it would be too manual in case OP has many columns, no?

Comment: Right. I see what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

I changed the indexing from `c(.N+1, 1:.N)` to `c(1L, 1:.N)` (from @David Arenburg's post) as it is easier in this way :-)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[c(1L,1:.N)], by=ID][, 2:3 := .SD*(!duplicated(.SD, 
           fromLast=TRUE))+0L, .SDcols=2:3][]
#   ID TIME DV DOSE  pH
#1:  1    0  0   50 4.6
#2:  1    1  5   50 4.6
#3:  1    5 10   50 4.6
#4:  2    0  0  100 6.0
#5:  2    1  6  100 6.0
#6:  2    7 10  100 6.0
```

Or you could use `set` that updates by reference (if there are many columns)

```
 DT <- setDT(df)[, .SD[c(1L, 1:.N)], by=ID]
 indx <- DT[, !duplicated(.SD, fromLast=TRUE), .SDcols=2:3]
 for(j in 2:3){
     set(DT, i=NULL, j=j, value= DT[[j]]*(indx+0L))
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

A concise approach using `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)

ldply(split(df, df$ID), function(u){x=u[1,];x[c("DV","TIME")]=0;rbind(x,u)})

#  .id ID TIME DV DOSE  pH
#1   1  1    0  0   50 4.6
#2   1  1    1  5   50 4.6
#3   1  1    5 10   50 4.6
#4   2  2    0  0  100 6.0
#5   2  2    1  6  100 6.0
#6   2  2    7 10  100 6.0
```